# How to use form submit in a bootstrap dropdown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-form

So I have the following code :

```
   {!! Form::open(['action'=>['AdminController@update',$upload->id], 'method'=>'POST']) !!}
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Filter
                        </button>
                        {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
                        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-success'])}}
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/manage">Approve</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/manage">Reject</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {!! Form::close()!!}
```

Instead of having the :

```
                      {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
                        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-success'])}}
```

I'd like to use the `dropdown items` in order to submit data to the controller.

I tried having something like this :

```
 {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
     <a class="dropdown-item" onclick="{{Form::submit()}}" href="/manage">Approve</a>
```

The above didn't really work for me(actually it does work, but I don't want to submit with the button, but with the dropdown `items`). Can I combine the `Form::submit` and the dropdown items, such that when an item is clicked a `submit` is made?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a bit of jQuery

```
 $(".dropdown-item").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     $("form").submit();

});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. and it is partly working. For some reason it is always sending the id of the last row to {!! Form::open(['action'=>['AdminController@update',$upload->id], 'method'=>'POST']) !!}

Comment: @RobertRoss That's because you are not passing id of dropdown to form submit, add an input field and then in the code above pass the id of to that input and in the controller get the id and do the thing on it

Comment: I'd appreciate if you demo this, since I am not sure what you mean. If i use the original code with the submit button the id is always correct.